# Deploying JSF Application with Virtual host in TomcatServer

Tags: jsf, tomcat, virtualhost, mojarra

I am using Mojarra 2.0.4 implementation of JSF with Tomcat server for one of my application, now i came to a problem during its deployment. I had added a virtual host to the Tomcat server.xml as follows,

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>

            <Host name="www.edgeutil308.com"  appBase="webapps/EdgeUtil"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      <Alias>edgeutil308.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="."/>

 </Host>
```

The problem which i am facing is that my mojarra implementation initializes twice as like below\

### INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.4 (FCS b06) for context ''

---

INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.4 (FCS b06) for context '/EdgeUtil'

and also i couldnot get the application run without using the project name as its context path like this

www.edgeutil308.com/EdgeUtil

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some mismatch with your appBase definitions. The appbase for the `edgeutil308` host is inside the appbase for the `localhost` host.